# MySite Creation

Tags: user-profile-service, mysite

Following on from my original question - [SharePoint Farm requiring DC](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252639/does-sharepoint-farm-require-a-domain-controller)

I successfully got this to work, and have all the required profiles available in CA now.

Now that the User Profile service has been populated - Can a MySite be created for each user added? Through the 'Setup My Sites' section on CA, or is this just a general set up for My Sites?

The end goal here is to create an intranet with a staff directory (containing all staff) without the requirement for having everyone log in.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can a MySite be created for each user added? Through the 'Setup My Sites' section on CA, or is this just a general set up for My Sites?**

**No,** You will **first** need to

- Configure `My site host` as a site collection and it's preferred to create it below independent web application!
- Then you can configure my site setting from CA "Set up my site".
- Now, when each user goes to his/her profile, his/her mysite site collection will be provisioned automatically using self-creation feature.

> **Note:** The below application services should be configured before configuring MySite
>
> - User Profile Service application
> - Managed Metadata service application
> - Search service application - not mandatory

---

**Configure Mysite Steps**

- Create a dedicated web application & My Site host site collection
- Add a wildcard inclusion managed path to the web application
- Enable self-service site creation for the web application
- Create a permission policy & Grant everyone permission to My Site web application
- Configure My Site settings for the User Profile service application

Check the details steps at [Configure My Sites in SharePoint 2016 - Step by Step Guide](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/configure-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2016-step-by-step.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question itself. In SharePoint server **mysites is a personal site created for every user**.

Although a My Site appears as a single site to a user, the My Sites architecture in SharePoint Server consists of a web application, a My Site host site collection, an individual site collection, and several SharePoint service applications and features.

Except for the individual site collection, **all other parts of this infrastructure are configured once and shared among all the users** who are part of the My Sites deployment.

So the end goal that you wish can be fulfilled with mysite.